# aiohttp - Webssocket - msgs in buffer after ws.close()?

Tags: python, websocket, aiohttp

I am receiving updates about the state of some financial markets from a websocket server. However, due to limitations imposed by the server, I must periodically create a new ws connection.

The first msg from the newly established connection is an initial state and subsequent messages are small 'delta' messages which just let you know how to update the state. I haven't included implementation details for this, but I re-initialize my internal state object when I establish a new connection.

I have the following coroutine to handle incoming websocket messages, and periodically close and establish a new ws connection:

```
async def foo():
    async with session.ws_connect('wss://example.com') as ws:
        initialize_time = datetime.now()
        async for msg in ws:
            if datetime.now() - initialize_time > timedelta(seconds=3000):
                await ws.close()
                loop.create_task(foo())
                return
            else:
                # process the msg
```

Perhaps this is dubious design. (Is it?)

My experience is that I get no errors during the time (1 whole hour) I don't close and re-open the connection, but always get an error soon after the re-open in my state update logic - for example, it attempts to update a market with an id not in the current state.

So my suspicion is that messages in the buffer of the first ws connection when its closed are then later retrieved by the 'async for msg in ws:' loop of the new ws connection. I could be barking up the wrong tree though. Is there a way to purge the msgs currently in the buffer? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on unread messages in websocket buffer.
The websocket message delivery is not atomic operation, there is a possibility to have in-flight messages which was sent be peer but not delivered to the node yet at the moment of websocket closing.

Comment: Ok thanks. After I have done 'await ws.close()' what happens when an in-flight message arrives? Does it get added to the buffer or discarded? I mean if I haven't yet returned from the coroutine and execution is still inside the 'async for msg in ws:' loop.